# Reply button not working

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro, which uses Safari as the web browser.
When I check my company's e-mail online, I cannot use the Reply button (it simply does not respond.)

I wonder what I should do to fix this problem. (My computer is new.)

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: @mipadi.The computer has only one browser. I have not downloaded any other.

Answer (score 1):

Does anything else not work, or is it just the “Reply” button? A few things you could try:

- **Restart Safari**—or your computer. Sounds dumb, but it's amazing how often this does the trick.
- Use the menu item “Safari -> Empty Cache…” to **clear Safari’s cache**.
- Try to use your company’s webmail **in another browser**. There may be a subtle bug (or feature?) in the website’s code that Safari is not handling properly. Here are a few alternatives:

  - [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/)
  - [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/)
  - [Opera](http://www.opera.com/)
  - [OmniWeb](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omniweb/)
  - [Camino](http://caminobrowser.org/)
  - [Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/), on Windows, just to check. Even in this day and age, some websites still only work properly with IE.
  - [Netscape Navigator](http://browser.netscape.com/releases/) (Yuk yuk yuk. Just kidding, don’t download this. For the love of God, don’t download this.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured out. It is that the Block Pop-up Window that was checked.

Comment: Oh, does it pop up a new window for you to compose your message in?

Comment: Yes. I uncheck the botton and it works now. Thanks.